# Finding a mistake in calculating $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ using contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let us calculate
$$I=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} $$
using contour integral. I want to know what is wrong with the following argument.

Let $C$ denote the contour around the branch cut from $z=-1$ to $z=1$, wrapping around each branch point with small circular arcs with radius $\epsilon$. Since $\sqrt{1-z^2}=\sqrt{(1-z)(1+z)}\sim \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\epsilon})$ for the small circular arcs each centered at $z=-1, z=1$, the $dz=\epsilon e^{i\theta} id\theta$ make the small circular arc contributions vanish. Since there is a branch cut (-1 sign difference in the upper and lower part of the integral), the contour integral becomes
$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} = 2I =0$$
where in the last equality, I used the residue theorem and used the fact that there are no simple poles.

However, the result should be $I=\pi$.  Where is wrong?

Comment: You can not do both. If there is a cut on $(-1,1)$ you can not use the residue theorem, and if there isn't (as actually in your case) you don't get your original integral out of it. As it stands, there is a branch cut on $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: The original problem doesn't change, when you use the principal branch of $\sqrt{...}$ as $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: In the case of cut existing on $(-1,1)$, is the reason why the residue theorem cannot be applied is because the function giving rise to the cut is not holomorphic on a simply-connected open subset (even without finite number of points subtracted)?

Also, I thought the branch cut can be chosen at will, as in this case, $(-1,1)$ or $(-\infty, -1) \cup (1,\infty)$.

Comment: About the branch cut: Yes you are right (see 2nd comment before yours). The main problem is the function is not holomorphic on a continuous subset of points of the domain.

Comment: If you like you can use your contour, but consider that it surrounds everything outside the curve.  Then when you look for singularities inside the contour, you have to include the point $z = \infty$.

Comment: What you might be able to do however is using $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2+z}$$ where $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ (which fixes your branch-cut) and then interchange the order of integration. Now you only have discrete singularities.

Comment: @GEdgar Applying (maybe or maybe not) the same logic, I get $\oint_C z^{-1} dz=0$ for $C$ being a unit circle by saying that it surrounds everything outside the curve. What's the issue in this case?

Comment: @Nugi ... No issue.  You have to evaluate the resuidue at $\infty$ (which turns out to be nonzero) to get your answer.

Comment: @Diger In the double integration you gave there, setting $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ fixes the branch cut to be $(-1,1)$ or $(-\infty, -1)\cup (1,\infty)$ or something else?

Comment: @GEdgar Thankful to receive one helpful point. :)

Comment: $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Diger I think I see, since otherwise the contour passes region outside the domain. Thankful to receive help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add another full example. Consider the contour integral $$I_R=\oint_{|z|=R} \frac{{\rm d}z}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
for some large $R$ counter-clockwise. The integrand is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, except at $z=0$ where it has a simple pole and the cut is chosen to be $(-\infty,-1) \cup (1,\infty)$ i.e. the principal-branch of the square-root selects the argument from $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Estimating the integral gives $$|I_R| \leq \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{{\rm d}t}{\sqrt{|1-R^2 e^{2it}|}} \leq \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{R^2-1}}$$
and so it vanishes for $R\rightarrow \infty$.

We can now deform the contour to enclose the 3 singularities separately counter-clockwise which gives $$I_\infty = 0 = \oint_{(-\infty,-1)} \frac{{\rm d}z}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}} + \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{{\rm d}z}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}} + \oint_{(1,\infty)} \frac{{\rm d}z}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}} = J_- + I_1 + J_+ \, .$$
Since the integrand only has a pole at $z=0$ inside of $|z|=1$, we can readily evaluate $I_1=2\pi i$ using the residue theorem. On the other hand $$J_+=\int_{1-i0}^{\infty-i0} \frac{{\rm d}z}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}} + \int_{\infty+i0}^{1+i0}\frac{{\rm d}z}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}} = -2i \int_1^\infty \frac{{\rm d}z}{z\sqrt{z^2-1}} = -2i \int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
where the last equality arises after substituting $z \rightarrow \frac{1}{z}$. Similarly you will find $J_-=J_+ $ and hence $$0=2\pi i - 4i \int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \, .$$